# Problema con map en React

Tags: reactjs, html-tabla

Buenas tardes compañeros, soy programador junior y estoy realizando una prueba para un trabajo como frontend con react. La descripción es sencilla.

> una vista con un calendario del mes actual (Vista tipo calendario vamos). Al darle click en un día saldrá un modal con un formulario de “Añadir Cita” que nos pedirá un titulo, hora de inicio y hora de final. Al guardarlo se vera en el calendario listado dentro del día que toca. Si hay mas de una cita el mismo día se mostraran ordenadas contando la hora de inicio (no tengas en cuenta en el caso que se solapen…)<

He desarrollado un par de componentes y una api para guardar los datos, la cuestion es que quiero pintar los días con una tabla y quiero que un map me lo haga automáticamente pero me encontrado un problema.

He añadido un ternario para que cambie de TR en los días donde se acaba la semana para que salga bien maquetado pero React no me deja hacerlo tal y como quiero, me preguntaba si se os ocurre como podría lograrlo.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './Calendar.scss';
import axios from "axios";
import Day from "./Day/Day";

export default function Calendar() {
   const [days, setDays] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
       axios.get('http://localhost:5000/January').then(res => {
           setDays(res.data)
       });
   }, [])

   return (
       <div className="b-calendar">
           <h3 className="e-title">January</h3>
           <table className="b-table">
               <thead>
                   <tr >
                       <th>Lunes</th>
                       <th>Martes</th>
                       <th>Miercoles</th>
                       <th>Jueves</th>
                       <th>Viernes</th>
                       <th>Sabado</th>
                       <th>Domingo</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               <tr>
                   {days.map((item, index) =>
                           (item.id !== 4 || item.id !== 11 || item.id !== 18 || item.id !== 25) ?

                                   <td key={index}>
                                       <Day items={item}/>
                                   </td>

                               :
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                               <td key={index}>
                                   <Day items={item}/>
                               </td>
                           )}
                       </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>

       </div>

   )
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias aclarar que es lo que no te deja hacer react?

Comment: en el inicio de la segunda condición del ternario, el cierre y apertura de las etiquetas <tr> me las marca como error [enlace](https://i.gyazo.com/15df7ba7400eb4a175b255f3fe25f50f.png)

Answer (score 1):

Una de las fallas es que al momento de realizar el ternario no estas indicando que debe devolver un elemento del DOM con un `return` o con un `()`, que es la forma en que React reconoce que debe *pintar* un input.

Adicional a eso, debes encerrar el `tr` también al momento de realizar el `map`, de lo contrario la tabla que estas construyendo se verá afectada visualmente

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Gokú"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Vegeta"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Piccolo"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Gohan"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Trunks"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(list);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="b-calendar">
        <h3 className="e-title">January</h3>
        <table className="b-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map((item, index) =>
              (item.id !== 1 || item.id !== 2) ? (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                </tr>
              ) : null
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Con esto debería ser suficiente; de todas maneras te recomiendo que construyas una función para que realices esa validación y tengas todo más centralizado en tu código.

Nos comentas si te sirve :)

Comment: lo siento porque en efecto me doy cuenta que no me explicado del todo bien, el problema que al ser un calendario, quiero cambiar de columna cada 7 días para que se organice cada row de lunes a domingo y se quede con la misma forma que tenemos cualquier calendario, es por esto que intentaba abrir el tr fuera del ternario, cerrarlo y volver abrirlo de nuevo dentro para seguir pintando datos y esto es lo que no consigo hacerlo ni se me ocurre como solucionarlo